# DC-DC converter outputing wrong voltage

Tags: voltage, dc-dc-converter

I am working on a small hobby project and need to use a DC-DC converter for it. I am using a Traco TME0303S. I checked the input voltage and it is 3.29 volts. For some reason though, when I check across Vout though, I'm getting 4.64 volts which makes no sense to me.

https://www.tme.eu/en/details/tme0303s/dc-dc-converters/traco-power/

Does a load need to be applied for the voltage to be correct on Vout? I haven't hooked up the load yet because the input voltage needs to be 3.3V and I don't want to burn it out.

Comment: Have you checked the ripple (AC mode on DMM)?  put a 10k resistor across the load

Comment: Good thinking to check before connecting your parts! 

Reading the spec, the output voltage is supposed to stay within 10% for a load variation from 20% to 100% of max. The fact that they _don't_ guarantee the output voltage when the load is less than 20% of max is a red flag.

 As VoltageSpike suggests (such an appropriate name!) put a resistor across the output and retest, but to draw 20% of max current (max=260mA) it will have to be much lower: 3.3V / .052A = 63 ohms.

Comment: After applying a 10k resistor, the DC voltage reads 3.84V. I tried checking ripple but I'm getting 0. I'm not sure if my Multimeter might be too cheap to properly read it.

Comment: I was able to apply a 60 Ohm load since i didn't have the correct resistors to make 63 and got a voltage of 3.54. It sounds like I should buy some better voltage converters. Thanks for explaining the spec! I now know what to look for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Does a load need to be applied for the voltage to be correct on Vout?*

Yes it does: -

[image]

These are bargain basement isolators and need a load in the range 20% to 100% of full-load specified in the data sheet. Also note their poor input voltage regulation figure.

Answer (score 0):

This is an unregulated isolated converter - as such, it seems to be performing as expected for that class of converter.

This type of converter requires a minimum load as the output is not regulated and at low output currents (such as no-load) the output voltage can rise.

They often consist of just a simple two transistor oscillator feeding the primary of a transformer with a bridge rectifier and a smoothing capacitor on the output. No regulation. The output voltage will be approximately proportional to the input voltage.

Their advantage is a low cost, small size and low heat dissipation.

If you need regulation but do not need isolation you may be better served by a non-isolating converter, many low-cost modules are available in this arrangement.

Comment: In this case, I did need isolation because I have analog sensors that I'm trying to obtain readings from concurrently that were interfering with each other.